# Galois Field $GF(6)$

Tags: field-theory

The set called $GF(6)=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ also has the mathematical operations addition modulo $6$ and multiplication modulo $6$. We want to prove that this is not a field, since it does not match with the law of fields. In which one do we see the mistake?

Comment: Hint: $2\cdot 3 = 6 = 0$.

Comment: why equal to 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** In this one:$$(\forall x\in K\setminus\{0\})(\exists y\in K):xy=yx=1.$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84737/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-carlos-santos-galois-field-gf6).

Answer (score 0):

For $GF$ to be a field it has to have for every element (except for $0$) an multiplicative inverse. Hence only $1$ and $5$ has one and the others don’t, it’s not an field. For every finite field such as it has an number of elements which is not prime $p$ many or $p^n$ for $n$ is natural, it can’t be an field.